# Can't figure out how to align horizontally text to left of input

Tags: html, css

this is a very beginner question, but I have been trying to figure out a way to have the Name, Email, and Age aligned to the left of the input fields. And then have it centered on the input boxes.

[Here](https://codepen.io/thehiddencheese/pen/WyEwOr) is a link to my codepen.io

I have tried floating the text to the left and making the inputs display as blocks. The input seems to be stuck having an extremely wide width which is making the text not display properly. If I manage to shrink the width of the box, and want to adjust the padding it makes the input box bigger! Instead of moving the the text and input left or right.

```css
#text-label {
  width: 50%;
}

#text-input {
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#email-input {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

#number-input {
  width: 80%;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="name-email-age">
  <div id="name" class="center">
    <label id="text-label">
            * Name:
          </label>
    <input id="text-input" type="text" name="Enter your name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
    <div id="email" class="center">
      <label id="email-label">
            * Email:
          </label>
      <input id="email-input" type="email" name="Enter your email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required />
    </div>
    <div id="age" class="center">
      <label id="age-label">
            * Age:
          </label>
      <input id="number-input" type="number" name="Enter your age" placeholder="Enter your Age" required max="122" min="5" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the input display styles to `inline-block`.

https://codepen.io/AustinGordon/pen/yEodLo

Comment: Don't just link to your solution. Add the relevant information to the body of your answer.

Comment: You just made me realize something... I changed it to inline-block on my codepen and it was still messed up, looked at yours and it was fine. Then I realized.. I had the editor window stretched out so it was making everything push together.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your can try this:

Wrap labels and controls in .control-group for optimum spacing 
and change box to ideal size =).

```css
#text-label {
  width: 50%;
}

#text-input {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}

#email-input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#number-input {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.control-group {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="name-email-age">
    <div id="name" class="center">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label id="text-label">* Name:</label>
            <input id="text-input" type="text" name="Enter your name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="email" class="center">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label id="email-label">* Email:</label>
            <input id="email-input" type="email" name="Enter your email" placeholder="Enter your Email" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="age" class="center">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label id="age-label">* Age:</label>
            <input id="number-input" type="number" name="Enter your age" placeholder="Enter your Age" max="122" min="5" required />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```